# Dynamically generated generic type not working properly

Tags: .net, vb.net, generics, .net-core, reflection

the following code works without any issue:

```
 Dim SubmodelElement = New BaSyx.Models.Core.AssetAdministrationShell.Implementations.SubmodelElementTypes.[Property](Of Double)() With {
                .IdShort = "TestProperty1",
                .[Set] = Function(prop, val)
                             Return _test = val
                         End Function
        }
    SubmodelElement.[Get] = Function(prop)
                                Return 4711
                            End Function
```

What I am trying to do is to create those submodel elements dynamically for each property of my class with the following code:

```
For Each Eigenschaft As PropertyInfo In Me.GetType().GetProperties()
            If Eigenschaft.CanRead = True Then
                Dim Eigenschaftstyp As Type = Type.GetType(Eigenschaft.PropertyType.FullName)

                Dim GenerischerTypBasysProperty As Type = GetType(BaSyx.Models.Core.AssetAdministrationShell.Implementations.SubmodelElementTypes.Property(Of)).MakeGenericType(Eigenschaftstyp)
                Dim BasysEigenschaft = Activator.CreateInstance(GenerischerTypBasysProperty)

                BasysEigenschaft.IdShort = Eigenschaft.Name
                BasysEigenschaft.[Get] = Function(prop)
                                             'Return Eigenschaft.GetValue(Me)
                                             Return 4711
                                         End Function
                BasysEigenschaft.Set = Sub(ByVal Prop, ByVal Wert)
                                           Eigenschaft.SetValue(Me, Wert)
                                       End Sub
                MyBase.SubmodelElements.Add(BasysEigenschaft)
            End If
        Next
```

As seen in the debugger both objects (SubmodelElement and BasysEigenschaft are of same type).

[screenshot of values of submodelElement and BasysEigenschaft](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngZ5C.png)

Unfortunally the assigning of the [Get]-function, doesnt work in the second code snipet. I get this error

System.InvalidCastException: "Method invocation failed because 'Public Overrides Property Get() As BaSyx.Models.Core.AssetAdministrationShell.Generics.SubmodelElementTypes.GetPropertyValueHandler(Of Double)' cannot be called with these arguments:
Argument matching parameter 'value' cannot convert from 'VB$AnonymousDelegate_0(Of Object,Integer)' to 'GetPropertyValueHandler(Of Double)'."

[screenshot of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5e4H.png)

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Is there any additional information I can add for making it easier to help me solve this issue? C#-answers are also accepted..

Comment: You should also include the definition of `Property`, especially since the exact signatures of the `Get` is important here.

Comment: That having been said, some poking at this suggests that once you get into the world of constructed types, VB stops doing a bunch of nice convenience conversions between `Function(Of T)` etc. and corresponding delegate types, and you're going to have to construct the delegate yourself.

Comment: This Microsoft link may have some helpful info, keeping in mind that you'll have to translate from event / handler hookup into what you actually want to do: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/how-to-hook-up-a-delegate-using-reflection

Comment: Note that it's not good practice to use the default `Object` types on parameters in your `Function` and `Sub` lambdas; you don't get type inference because of your usage, and you may need to get these types exactly right for things to work.

Answer (score 0):

I discussed the issue with the creator of the SubmodelElemenntTypes.Property -Class.
Like Craig suggested Activator.CreateInstance-method does not create the type exactly as the new Property (of T) constructor. The following lines solve the problems.

```
        For Each Eigenschaft As PropertyInfo In Me.GetType().GetProperties()

        If Eigenschaft.GetCustomAttributes(Of BasysPropertyAttribute).Count > 0 Then

            If Eigenschaft.CanRead = True Then


                If Eigenschaft.CanRead = True Then
                    Dim Eigenschaftstyp As Type = Type.GetType(Eigenschaft.PropertyType.FullName)

                    Dim BasysDataTypeXsd As DataType = DataType.GetDataTypeFromSystemType(Eigenschaftstyp)
                    Dim BasysEigenschaft As BaSyx.Models.Core.AssetAdministrationShell.Implementations.SubmodelElementTypes.Property = DirectCast(SubmodelElementFactory.CreateSubmodelElement(ModelType.Property, BasysDataTypeXsd), BaSyx.Models.Core.AssetAdministrationShell.Implementations.SubmodelElementTypes.Property)


                    BasysEigenschaft.IdShort = Eigenschaft.Name
                    BasysEigenschaft.[Get] = Function(BasysProperty As Object)
                                                 Return New ElementValue(Eigenschaft.GetValue(Me), BasysDataTypeXsd)
                                             End Function
                    BasysEigenschaft.[Set] = Sub(ByVal BasysProperty As Object, ByVal Wert As ElementValue)
                                                 Eigenschaft.SetValue(Me, CTypeDynamic(TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(Eigenschaftstyp).ConvertFromString(Nothing, Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, Wert.Value), Type.GetType(Eigenschaft.PropertyType.FullName)))
                                             End Sub
                    MyBase.SubmodelElements.Add(BasysEigenschaft)

                End If


            End If

        End If

    Next
```

Thanks to Craig for your help!

Comment: You're welcome, I'm happy to learn you were able to solve the problem.